# slideDown does not work for the first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I'm adding animation to show a hidden div when a checkbox is changed,

The first time it's clicked the div appears with no animation but it works both ways after the first time.

**How can I make it work also on the first time?**

Here is my div (also using bootstrap)

```js
    var postOptionsSourcesWrapper = $("#post-options-sources-wrapper");
    var postOptionsExclusiveCheckbox = $("#post-exclusive-cb");
    postOptionsExclusiveCheckbox.change(function() {
      if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        postOptionsSourcesWrapper.slideUp(300, "easeOutCirc", function() {
          postOptionsSourcesWrapper.addClass("hidden");
        });
      } else {
        postOptionsSourcesWrapper.removeClass("hidden");
        postOptionsSourcesWrapper.slideDown(300, "easeOutCirc");
      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="post-options-sources-wrapper" class="margin-b-5 hidden">
  <label class="text-md thick-600">Original post references</label>
  <div class="box-marker box-marker-white">
    <div class="thick-600 color-gray text-sm text-uppercase">
      Add one or multiple sources.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE: this issue is solved by adding display:none; to the div**

When adding the bootstrap class .hidden to hide for some reason it's not adding the display:none; that is part of the .hidden class in bootstrap... not sure why, but adding the style display:none; or calling postOptionsSourcesWrapper.hide() solves this issue.

Comment: I don't see the `#post-exclusive-cb` div in HTML.

Comment: You're also adding/removing your own '.hidden' class - what does this include?

Comment: hidden is a bootstrap class .hidden { display: none !important; }

Comment: #post-exclusive-cb is just a checkbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will achieve what you want to achieve.
You just have to replace your script with this one.

```
var postOptionsSourcesWrapper = $("#post-options-sources-wrapper");
var postOptionsExclusiveCheckbox = $("#post-exclusive-cb");

postOptionsSourcesWrapper.hide();

postOptionsExclusiveCheckbox.change(function() {
    postOptionsSourcesWrapper.slideToggle(300,postOptionsSourcesWrapper.is(":checked"));
});
```